# PHP: Set variable in to include file in 'if' statement

Tags: php, if-statement, include, echo

I am trying to set a variable in an `if` statement so that only when the `if` statement is true, the variable will be set and will be able to be used further down on the page.

Here's what I have tried:

```
if ($row[8] == 1) {
    echo 'Message here';
    ob_start();
    include('F164.php');
    $f164 = ob_get_clean();
}
```

as well as:

```
if ($row[8] == 1) {
    echo 'Message here';
    $f164 = include('F164.php');
}
```

Comment: Why dont these work, can you include the errors that you care getting?

Comment: What are you trying to set the variable to? Why don't you put a function in the include file, and call the function?

Comment: @Chausser When using `ob_start(); include('F164.php'); $f164 = ob_get_clean();` the file simply does not show up.  When using `$f164 = include('F164.php');` it does, but where it is declared, not where the variable is further down on the page.

Comment: What does the `if` statement have to do with this? The way you're trying to set the variable won't work outside the `if`, either.

Comment: @Barmar I would like the "if" statement to set the variable `$f164` to `include('F164.php');` only if `$row[8] == 1`.

Comment: Assignments work the same whether they're in an if statement or not. You need to figure out how to set the variable in the first place, the if statement is incidental.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `$f165 = eval(file_get_contents("F164.php"))`?

Comment: @Barmar Would I be implementing that into the "if" statement, or just as a variable declaration?  Using `eval(file_get_contents` doesn't seem to load the files.

Comment: Whatever you do, you do it the same way in an if statement or in top-level code. That was my only point -- the if statement is not the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### new answer:

```
<?php
if ($example === 123) {
    ob_start();
    include 'file_with_output.php';
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
?>
```

**Just tried, this works for me.**

**If this does not work for you, please give an example content of the included file.**

#### old answer:

I assume the value of the variable is in the **F164.php** file.
You can assign it by returning the value in the included file:

**F164.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
    $somevar = 'lolvalue';
    return $somevar;
?>
```

**Code:**

```
if ($example == true) {
    $var = include 'F164.php';
}
```

**Means:**
If *$example is true*, *$var* will get the value *'lolvalue'*.

**Edit:**

After reading your question again and again, i'm not sure if we mean the same thing. Still hope i could help.

Comment: Actually that sets `$example` to `true`... You missed an equals sign ;)

Comment: Let's say the file the code is from is called "header.php."  "F164.php" is a file with `<div>`'s that are supposed to be displayed at the bottom of the "header.php" if `$row[8] == 1`, but the code in the original question is up near the top.  Also, please note, and I should have said this before, "F164.php" has no variables declared at this time.